# element onClick not working with ngClick

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an attribute directive with the following code:

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  priority: 1000,
  link: function (scope, $element) {
    $timeout(function () {
      $($element).on('click','li', function ($event) {
        alert('hi');
      });
    });

  }
};
```

This is the HTML I'm trying to use it on:

```
<ul some-directive>
   <li ng-click="someFunc()"></li>
   <li ng-click="someFunc()"></li>
   <li ng-click="someFunc()"></li>
</ul>
```

the thing is that also on the li elements I am using ngClick directives to call some other function. What i noticed is that as long as the ngClick directives are there the directive onClick method never gets called.

Any way to make both the ngClick and the onClick to trigger?
it seems like the ngClick is overriding the directive's onClick.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  This seems like the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: I have a ul element with li elements in it with horizontal slide. I want to make a directive that when the user clicks an li it will be centered. I already have all the logic needed for that. but the thing is that because the li elements have ng-click on them it doesn't call the on('click')

Comment: But why can't you just modify the existing click handler?  Why do you need or want two different ones?

Comment: I have few of those sliders across my app. each one should center the li element on click but have a different purpose on it's own view. this is why I need both ngClick and on('click'). I have updated my post with a HTML example

Comment: whatever you want to do with ng-click, do in the link function click event and if you need controller define controller as well and use pretty much better.

Comment: inside the ul the li elements probably will be rendered using ngRepeat from some array and send some params to the ngClick function they're calling. it is not answering my problem just trying to set a workaround. but i need that directive to be as abstract as it can. I cannot know what element it will be used on, all I know is just that it needs to center horizontally the element that was clicked

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not quite sure why you need 2 clickhandler?
You could include a `<span>` inside the `<li>` and attach an onClick or ng-click method on that span.
Something like:

```
<li mydirective=""><span ng-click="handleClick()">your content here</span></li>
```

The content of the `<li>` element just goes inside the `<span>` then.

Comment: I have updated my post so you can see an example for what i wish to get

Comment: It would be invalid HTML to have a `<div>` between a `<ul>` and its child `<li>`, if you care about having valid HTML...

Comment: You're totally right of course, sorry! I updated my answer.